# Erlang socket send timeout never happens

Tags: sockets, ssl, erlang

I am implementing a TCP Server in Erlang which talks to mobile phone clients.
Mobile phones get offline a lot, so the server must be able to detect it.
Hence I want the server to send messages to clients with a timeout, so that when the timeout happens the connection is closed and the client are marked as offline.

I used this listen option on the server:

```
[{certfile, "cert.pem"},   
 {keyfile, "key.pem"},
 {reuseaddr, true},   
 {active, false},
 {send_timeout, 10000}]
```

After I set up the connection between the server and the mobile phone, I switch the phone to airplane mode (which shuts down all wireless signals), and do an `ssl:send` on the server. The send function happliy returned `ok` as if the packet is successfully transmitted.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Where did you get that send_timeout from? Looking at the `ssl` module I don't see that option.

Comment: He got that from `inet`. If using `ssl:connect/4` for instance, you can supply any socket option, including timeouts from `inet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set the `{send_timeout_close, true}` parameter on the socket from `inet`? If not, the socket won't be closed, just return back a timeout error. There is also the risk `ssl` swallows your error and does something with it.

Some other points:

- Remember to check the return value of any `ssl:send` and `ssl:receive` options for error. It is important to know that the send went well.

  ```
  ok = ssl:send(Sock, Data),
  ```
- The underlying TCP/IP stack might actually accept the data even with a `send_timeout` set, but won't be able to send it as the other endpoint is down. The knowledge of the closed port first arrives later on, when the stack realizes it never got an ACK.
- There is a `raw` entry type for Sockets, defined in `inet`. It allows you to set OS-specific socket options. It may be possible to coerce the OS into being more aggressive at detecting the loss of a connection.
- Another option is to cue everything on a `ssl:recv/3` call where a timeout signifies loss of the device, regardless of its socket status. It has the advantage of also detecting application trouble in the other end as it does not progress along the determined path. You will have to do this for processing further requests anyway.
- The mobile phone client can also act. If it send's a message over SSL and the receive never arrives (due to airplane mode) - then it knows something is wrong. The server may not know this however.
- TCP/IP provides a reliable, connection-oriented stream protocol. It does not guard against sudden disconnects. This is important as your protocol *must* handle the disconnect problem itself. It is especially important if your protocol has some kind of confirmation or acknowledgement.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. I have set the send_timeout_close but the ssl:send always returns ok. It seems that ssl:send does not wait for the ACK, but rather depends on some system call which returned success all the time.