# Is the call to ssl:send/2 blocking?

Tags: ssl, erlang, send, block

I am making use of a SSL socket which is upgraded from a TCP Socket. When I am trying to send some data through that socket using [`ssl:send/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#send-2), it blocks. I have `send_timeout` option for the underlying TCP Socket. 
Can someone please tell me why `ssl:send` hangs and what is the solution to it?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322532/erlang-socket-send-timeout-never-happens

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Try adding the option {buffer, 0} when you open the socket to see if its caused by inet buffering.